# How to get obj from a start_data and a end_data using Django?

Tags: mysql, django

I have a table named `location`, and I want to get some data between two dates.

I use this:

```
location.objects.filter(time>start_data, time<end_data)
```

but I think maybe not right.

What can I do using django? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to sushanath's answer, you can also use the date range lookup
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range

```
location.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use date_*gte  date*_lte django

```
location.objects.filter(time__gte=2011-03-01,time__lte=2011-03-05)
```